# When should I submit my Django form's results?

Tags: python, django

The contents of my form must be submitted to another application server for validation and execution (specifically, I call a RESTful web service with the posted values in the form). The service will either return a 200 SUCCESS or a 400/409 error with a body that describes the exact field errors.

When should I do this submission? Should I do it in the view:

```
if form.is_valid:
    result = submit_to_service(POST)
    if result.code in (400, 409):
        somehow_set_errors_on_the_form(form)
    else:
        go_on...
```

Or in the Form.clean method?

```
def clean(self):
    result = submit_to_service(POST)
    if result.code in (400, 409):
        for field in result.errors:
            self._errors[field].append(result.errors[field])
    else:
        pass
```

Which of these is clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> validation and execution

No execution or stateful changes in the form `clean()`.  Please.  The form's `clean()` should only mess with data on the form, not anywhere else.

If there is a stateful change, it **must** be in a view function inside a non-GET request handler.

Comment: can you give a brief example please?

Comment: @AJ: I don't need to.  Example 1 in the question -- if it occurs in a view function -- is better.

Comment: S.Lott, how do you respond to Gregor's answer, below? His comment about ModelForm's `save` method seems pretty relevant.

Comment: @Chris R: I totally disagree with that approach.  The `form.save()` must not interact with outside services.  The semantics of this method are clear.  It has to handle a `commit=False` option properly; working with an outside service may make `commit=False` impossible to implement.  The web service may make a change that is auto-committed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually encapsulate these type of logic in the form. Since you use the form to validate the data you also use it to send the data. This makes sense because the form already knows about the data and its types etc (it has the `cleaned_data` dictionary).

But processing data and changing state of your application should not live directly *inside* your validation logic (e.g. in your `clean` method). You should put it in an extra method of your form - like `ModelForm` is doing it with the `save()` method.

So my suggestion is to have an extra method named `save()` (if the method actually *saves* your processing to the REST service) or `post_result()` or something similar that fits better.

Here is an example:

```
# forms.py

class ValidateDataForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        # validation logic

    def save(self):
        post_results_to_service(self.cleaned_data)

# views.py

def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ValidateDataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ValidateDataForm()
```

---

The above assumes that the REST service is changing state for your
application, e.g. it implements some business logic. If this is not the case
and you only use the service as validation for the input data on your form -
and use the form data then for something different - I would suggest something
different.

In this case the code should go into the `clean()` method like you suggested
in your second code example.